# JNI coding, from Java to C

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a piece of code in Java to which I need to use JNI and write it up in C.

This method is called from another class, so 'newName' is passed to it from another class. I also have a Player class, which has a method to set player name. And then I return a String, containing 'newName' and  'dodMap.getGoal()' which is defined in another class.

```
public class gameLogic implements GameInterface {

private gameMap dodMap;
...


public String clientHello(String newName, Player player) {
    // Change the player name and then say hello to them
    player.setName(newName);
    return "HELLO " + newName + "\nGOAL " + dodMap.getGoal();
}
```

I have done some reading into JNI, and created a .h class 'javah' and got this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_gameLogic_clientHello (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jobject);
```

I know how to handle the string, however I don't know how to handle the player object and how to call dodMap.getGoal();

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you must do it with JNI, I'd suggest you look at [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "I need to use JNI and write it up in C."  Are you trying to replace your Java implementation of `gameLogic.clientHello()` with a native one?  If so, then why?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I'm trying to do that, and we are required to do it for a coursework. We need to change the method to a native one, and then implement the method in C

Comment: Instead of passing in an object pass in a serialized string. then deserialize in 'C' code.

Comment: @RomainHippeau Right, so I could that for the player object. However to get the 'dodMap.getGoal()', I would need to pass dodMap and not gameLogic right?

Comment: In the past to simplify not creating objects and passing those through language barriers, I have gotten away with passing simple , ints and strings . Simplifies the JNI code a lot. I do not have the details of what you need to pass, just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* access fields and methods of Java objects via JNI -- and that seems the intent of the exercise -- then you will want to familiarize yourself with the [JNI docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).  They contain examples for exactly the kinds of things you asked about, as well as a reference for all the JNI functions, and overall information that you need to know to use JNI.

Some of the JNI functions you will need are:

- [`GetFieldId()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetFieldID) and [`GetObjectField()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_type_Field_routines) to retrieve a pointer to the `dodMap`
- [`GetObjectClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetObjectClass), [`GetMethodId()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetMethodID), and [`CallVoidMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Call_type_Method_routines) to invoke `player.setName()` (presuming that that method returns `void`; else one of the other `Call<Type>Method()` functions would be needed).
- [`CallObjectMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Call_type_Method_routines) (or one of the other `Call<Type>Methods()`) in addition to some of the above to invoke `dodMap.getGoal()`.

Since you will not have Java strings to rely on for the fixed strings in your code, you will probably want to use C array manipulation to build the return value (as opposed, say, to using the methods already discussed to invoke `String.concat()`).  That involves functions including

- [`GetStringChars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringChars), [`GetStringLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringLength), [`ReleaseStringChars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#ReleaseStringChars), and [`NewString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewString), or alternatively, the UTF-8-based versions of these.

Do be sure to observe the distinction between `jchar` and `char`.

As you might have guessed from the number of different functions I just named, what you have been asked to do is neither simple nor fun (but it *is* doable).  Wherever possible, it is best to design JNI interfaces to minimize the need to work with Java objects in native code.

Comment: To retrieve that pointer to dodMap, would I need a separate method in my c class that does so? or can I point to it from the original method "JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_gameLogic_clientHello(..."

Comment: From the native code you can use a sequence of JNI function calls to get a reference to the `dodMap`.  The ultimate goal would be to use `GetObjectField()`.  To do that, you first need the appropriate field ID, which you can get from `GetFieldId()`.  As input to `GetFieldId()`, however, you need the `jclass` representing class `gameLogic`.  You can get that class via `FindClass()`.  (You could also use `GetObjectClass()` if you're willing to assume that the class of the object on which the native method is invoked is not a subclass.)

Comment: Hey, when I use the function GetFieldID to point to dodMap, It requires that I have a signature. However I'm not sure what the signature is meant to be for dodMap. I have done some research, and people suggest I use the package name in the signature, however I do not use any packages in my code. Is there a way to get its signature without using a package? Thanks.

Comment: @AmanKakkar, as I told you at the beginning, familiarize yourself with the JNI docs (that I linked).  As they pertain to field signatures, you will want https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures.  For a field having a reference type, you would want to use an `L` code, something like `Lmypackage/gameMap;`, but you have not provided enough information for me to give you an exact signature.  I'm sure you can work it out.

Comment: I have looked at them quite a bit, and I have found the same answers that you just gave me, to use the package name in the signature. However I do not have a package for any of my classes. I'm sorry for repeating myself, but is there a default package name I can use instead? or maybe the path to gameMap within the signature? or any other alternative?

Comment: My GetFieldID function currently looks like this: `jfieldID fid;
 fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, fieldName, "Ljava/lang/Class/gameMap;"); 
 assert(fid != NULL);`, I'm using the assert to check for errors, and it brings up an error

Comment: Generally speaking, you should *always* put your classes in packages.  If you do not do so, however, then they do go into the default package, which is anonymous.  All that is secondary, however; if class `gameMap` is in the default package then its fully-qualified name is simply `gameMap`.  It's unclear to me whether you can write a signature for that at all, but if you can do then it might be `LgameMap;` or `L/gameMap;` or perhaps even `L./gameMap;`.  You might be able to determine by searching for strings inside `gameLogic.class`, but better, just put your classes in a package.

Comment: Thanks for that, I used javap -s -p gameLogic to get the signature for dodMap, and it was LdodMap.